# FIlling and cleaning excel cells based on values in adjacent cells

Tags: excel, vba

Looking to clean Excel data and make it into a proper dataset using macro/formulae. This is how my data looks like.

[image]

Need to convert it like this:
[image]

The number of rows can reach >3000 and number of projects under each name is not constant. 
Few steps identified are:
1. Remove the blank rows against each task(marked in red)
2. Remove Utilization column
3. Available hours column to populate the value in each empty cell below.
4. Start data and End Date from cell L4 in two new columns
5. Team Name in cell A9 to be populated in a new column "Team Name"

I've tried using the recorded the macro but it doesn't work in a new data set. Hence looking for some expert help.

Comment: Look into Power Query. It'll be much easier that doing this with VBA.

Answer (score 0):

The keyword to identify what you have to do is unpivot. 
You can unpivot your data using:

- Power Query, following [these steps](http://www.exceltactics.com/how-to-unpivot-columns-into-rows-in-excel-using-power-query/);
- VBA macro, following [these steps](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/399106-transform-table-into-list-how-unpivot-table.html).

There are also others possible solutions to unpivot data...just use Google to find them.